# how to validate the date that it should not be before than today?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I m inserting date and the validation is it should not be before date than today.

I m using *jquery datepicker*.

Comment: Please remember to validate on the server side also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option [`minDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate), if you don't want user to be able select any date before a particular date.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date());
//Will set the minimum date that the user can select to Today.
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/Vc4av/)

Comment: it gives "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object" error

Comment: $("input#txtDate").datepicker({ altField: 'input#txtDate',minDate: new Date()}) this works fine as disables the past date but when i select future date or today's date it gives above mentioned error.

Comment: it should work...Try debugging using firebug..BTW why are you using `altField` the same field as your selector..

Comment: i m sorry but it still shows that error. and if i press break it breaks and if i press continue it continues after showing that error. error is somewhere here , for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();  webresource.axd..

Comment: yeah it work fine without altField also.but that length error is still there.

Comment: So it's the error in asp.net validator. I think you should get rid of that and do only the server side validation. Becasuse you already one kind of client side validation by setting `minDate`

Comment: it was because i had put require field validator on textbox control as soon as i remove that yout code worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
if (datePickerID.getTime() < date.getTime()) {
    write your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) control. Set the [ControlToValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx) to your `TextBox` control. Set the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) property to *Date*. And, set the [MaximumValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.maximumvalue.aspx) to the current date...

Refer to [Validation - RangeValidator](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/range-validator/)